# Usage Of "Make For "

Tags: phrase-usage

I am trying to figure out the correct usage of "made for".  Suppose human error caused an accident:

1. Human error led to the accident.
2. Human error ***made for*** the accident.

Is this usage of "*make for*" okay?

Answer (score 1):

We use "make for" to tally the factors that brought about a quality, desirable or otherwise, but not an event as such.

For example:

> Good friends, good food and great weather made for a fabulous picnic.

Here the three factors listed all conspired to bring about a "fabulous" picnic. The focus here is "what kind of picnic" and not the "picnic" per se.

> The speaker's shrill voice, coupled with the most boring subject
>   matter imaginable, made for the worst lecture I've ever attended.

Of your examples, only (1) correct, since (2) isn't idiomatic. In such cases, it's better to use "lead to" or "cause" or "bring about."

Comment: +1 because I agree the substantive point (OP's example #2 isn't idiomatic). But I don't really have a problem with [*The combination of the holiday, parties, command inertia and undermanned command posts and the fact that few harbor craft actually were on station to set out for an emergency on Christmas Eve **made for a disaster**.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Christmas+Eve+made+for+a+disaster%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), so I'm not convinced your "quality, not event" rationale properly explains the idiomatic preference.

Comment: I see your point, however is this an actual disaster or are they using "disaster" figuratively to describe the unnamed, unspecified event. My reasoning is that if you were to replace "disaster" with the actual event, say "an ambush" - it doesn't really work. Which brings us back to the "quality" question.

Comment: I think fairly obviously ***a disaster*** refers to a specific event there, just as *"Goodwill on all sides made for a successful outcome"* (or just *"...made for [a] success"*, which I find just about tolerable with or without the article). Yes, in practice whatever was "made for" will often be some "event" specifically qualified by a positive or negative adjective - which adjective wouldn't have applied had the contributing factor(s) not led to that particular outcome. But an "outcome" is essentially an event or object, not a *quality* of whatever result was encouraged by those factors.

Comment: Then why doesn't (2) work? By your reasoning, the "accident" is an event and it should be admissible in that sentence. In your last response you cited "a successful outcome, or just: a success." Here "a success" works figuratively like "a disaster" - a representative noun used to sum up the quality of the event without naming the event outright. When the event is named, it must be modified for "make for" to be idiomatic. For example, I think (2) wouldn't be so jarring if it read: Human error made for an unfortunate accident.

Comment: I think we probably have very similar ideas about which usages we're comfortable with, and which we're not. The problem is how to codify our reactions so *learners* can "derive" the same results. FWIW I don't much like *"Human error made for an unfortunate accident"* anyway, since I'm naturally led to assume there was going to be an accident regardless (but the contributing factor "human error" led to it being an *unfortunate* one).

Comment: Absolutely. I've been looking online for instances of "make for" and I can't find any with a bare noun as the result, unless that noun is used to represent the quality of the outcome (like disaster or success). Also, interestingly enough, the "event" is usually indefinite, even when referring to a specific event, e.g. my picnic sentence. This is a tough one and you're an excellent debater!

Comment: I can but echo your last sentence there. I can't help feeling we're either missing something, or haven't managed to find the right words to succinctly convey exactly what it is that guides our "acceptable/not acceptable" assessments. Note that I'm not convinced *"John made for a good party"* would ever really work, but *"Having John present made for a good party"* seems fine to me, as does *"The drunken gatecrashers made for a riotous party"*.

Comment: I think I have it. In this usage, "make for" doesn't account for the event or result or its cause, it accounts for it's outcome/quality. The event itself is randomized (hence the indefinite) and the focus is on the outcome in terms of a quality. Thus is it more copular in nature than transitive, i.e. it effectively paraphrases (due to such-and-such factor(s)), the [noun] was [adj], where the adj is focal. What do you think?

Comment: I think you're definitely getting closer! Perhaps we could say that in general, *"X makes for Y"* only works where ***Y*** is something that *was going to happen anyway* (such as my *party*) but the fact of ***X*** being involved caused it to be a particular kind of ***Y*** (a *good* party). If no such modification (*unfortunate* accident, *good* party) is specified, it has to be because ***X*** is an inherently value-laden noun equating to ***outcome*** (some kind of "outcome" was expected - was it good or bad?). But an ***accident*** wasn't going to "happen anyway", so it's just "weird".

Comment: That was extremely clear and logical. You should tighten it up and post it as an answer since it explains and expounds on my (now) superficial answer. Good job!

Comment: Let's leave it for a bit. These comments stand as testimony to some of the more obscure factors involved.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, #2 is standard English after all?

Comment: @meatie: I'd have thought it's obvious that neither myself nor CocoPop would endorse the usage, since this entire comment thread is mainly concerned with us trying to figure out a "rule" which would explain ***why we don't like it***. The short answer, as CocoPop says, and as I endorsed in my first comment and upvote, is ***(2) isn't idiomatic***. The long answer we're still trying to figure out, but for your purposes as a learner, the best advice is to avoid thinking of ***make for*** as synonymous with ***caused***. It's not.